# TIN interpolation out of extent

Tags: extents, tin, bathymetry

I have a problem with the TIN. I just started using QGIS because I no longer have access to ArcGIS. I want to create a reservoir bathymetry map from depth survey points. I created a polyline and converted it to a polygon so I can contain the interpolation within the shoreline boundary but when I run the TIN, it does not recognize the shoreline polygon as the extent and it interpolates out of that.

What is wrong?

Also is the TIN the most suitable for bathymetric interpolation or is there any other method?

It is for Lake Diefenbaker 180 km long, more similar to a river than a lake.

[image]

Comment: Well, the tin looks like a raster and I do not see your boundary in the input. There is one feature class, with type points and there should be another with type boundary/limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted a few web articles describing techniques for computing a lake or reservoir volume at:

https://gwlucastrig.github.io/TinfourDocs/#lake-and-reservoir-volume

The software I wrote to do this is all in Java, but the ideas should be applicable to other software environments.

Also, if you have your data in the form of shapefiles and can put them somewhere I can get them, I would be interested in attempting to process them.  Lake Diefenbaker is a bit different than other bodies of water I've analyzed and might provide a good test case for my implementations.